# Update using Spring+Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc

I want to perform a transaction using Hibernate+Spring.I want to retrieve the data from DB and update the parameter and then persist the same.I am new to hibernate can someone evaluate the code and suggest me the best approach to implement the same.Here is the code snippet:

```
@Repository
public class WalletDaoImpl implements WalletDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public boolean creditWallet(double amount, final String customerId) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Wallet.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("customerId", customerId));

        Wallet walletInfo = (Wallet) cr.uniqueResult();
        tx.commit();

        final double newbalaance = walletInfo.getAmount() + amount;
        walletInfo.setAmount(newbalaance);

        Transaction tx2 = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(walletInfo);
        tx2.commit();
        session.close();
        return true;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the best approach it to leave to Spring the transacion management; you shouls use the @Transactional annotation of spring and configure spring in order transaction annotation are enabled

So, returning at your code... I'd do something like this:

```
@Repository
public class WalletDaoImpl implements WalletDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public boolean creditWallet(double amount, final String customerId) throws Exception
    {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Wallet.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("customerId", customerId));

        Wallet walletInfo = (Wallet) cr.uniqueResult();
        final double newbalaance = walletInfo.getAmount() + amount;
        walletInfo.setAmount(newbalaance);
        session.update(walletInfo);
        return true;

    }
}

@Service
public class WalletServiceImpl implements WalletService
{
    @Autowired
    private WalletDao dao;
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean updateWallet(double amount, final String customerId) throws Exception
    {
        return dao.creditWallet(amount, customerId);

    }
}
```

A deeper explanitation is found here: [Spring transaction managment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I will implement this.But just wanted to know the  creditWallet implementation is fine and optimized or is there any better approach?

Comment: Another thisng is I am facing issue when I am using Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();.But its works fine when I use Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession(); Can you please tell me if its going to create any performance issue?

Comment: well generally you should use current session since hibernate use threadlocal strategy (it depends on how you configured it). try to add you hibernate+spring configuration; getCurrentSession is the best way to operate; openSession could be little bit more expansive